# Xamarin add view to layout but not visible at screen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-linearlayout, textview

From my code I try to add some view to screen (For add dynamic view control in future) but it not visible at my screen.
For var TextTest  at last line it show text result "0000000000000" .
What a property i need to set to TextView for show this control to layout ?

```
[Activity()]
public class LoginActivity : Activity
{ 
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ActionBar.Hide();
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login); 

        var layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.loginLayout); 
        var button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCallApi); 
        button1.Click += (se, ev) =>
        {
            var param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            var textView2 = new TextView(layout.Context) { Id = 123 };
            param.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, textView2.Id);
            textView2.Text = "0000000000000";
            textView2.SetX(300);  
            textView2.SetY(300);
            textView2.ScaleY = 300;
            textView2.ScaleX = 300;
            textView2.TextSize = 30;
            textView2.SetWidth(300);
            textView2.SetHeight(300);
            layout.AddView(textView2, param);
            layout.Invalidate();
            var newTx = FindViewById<TextView>(123);
            var TextTest = newTx.Text; 
        };
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify too many parameters at once, and most of them are not needed.

LinearLayout is placing its children automatically, so you don't need to specify their positions.

Besides, the scaling values are 300, effectively meaning this will scale the object 300 times i.e. to 30000% of the original size. I doubt that you want it.

So, summarizing this, for the beginning, get rid of most of the property changes, make text view appear and then start applying those parameters back (if you really need them) gradually.

```
// var param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
//ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
var textView2 = new TextView(layout.Context) { Id = 123 };
//param.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, textView2.Id);
textView2.Text = "0000000000000";
//textView2.SetX(300);
//textView2.SetY(300);
//textView2.ScaleY = 300;
//textView2.ScaleX = 300;
//textView2.TextSize = 30;
//textView2.SetWidth(300);
//textView2.SetHeight(300);
layout.AddView(textView2/*, param*/);
//layout.Invalidate();
//var newTx = FindViewById<TextView>(123);
//var TextTest = newTx.Text;
```